# headerViewForSection and footerViewForSection always returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

So in header for Section I create a custom view and return it to be displayed (the function returns a UIView)

the view is displayed and is behaving as normal in the app, however whenever I call headerViewForSection I get returned nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This hung me up for a little bit however I wanted to make a post to help others, the functions `headerViewForSection()` and `footerViewForSection()` actually return a value of type UITableViewHeaderFooterView?
although it will work and be fine with populating a UIView in the

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

if you ever want to retrieve it the OS will not return anything accept that of type or subclassed from UITableViewHeaderFooterView. Hope this helps some one

Comment: Yeah, the returned view needs to be subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView